# Implementation of [PARTITION BY] command by LINQ

Tags: c#, .net, linq, t-sql

I did my best search to convert `PARTION BY` command from `TSQL` to `LINQ` command. But apparently there is no way to convert it. 
This is my code to which I am going to convert:

```
WITH MyRowSet
AS
(
SELECT OrderDate
      ,SalesOrderNumber
      ,AccountNumber
      ,CustomerID
      ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY CustomerID ORDER BY CustomerID, OrderDate DESC) AS RowNum
FROM [Sales].[SalesOrderHeader] 
)
SELECT * FROM MyRowSet WHERE RowNum = 1
```

If exist any solution I would be greatful to know.

Answer (score 3):

[linq2db](https://github.com/linq2db/linq2db) has this feature among with CTE. If you already work with EF Core, you can extend your LINQ queries by extension [linq2db.EntityFrameworkCore](https://github.com/linq2db/linq2db.EntityFrameworkCore)

This SQL can be written by LINQ

```
var rnQuery = 
    from oh in db.SalesOrderHeader
    select new 
    {
       oh.OrderDate,
       oh.SalesOrderNumber,
       oh.AccountNumber,
       oh.CustomerID,
       RowNum = Sql.Ext.RowNumber().Over().PartitionBy(oh.CustomerID)
          .OrderByDesc(oh.OrderDate).ToValue()
    };

// switch to alternative LINQ Translator
rnQuery = rnQuery.ToLinqToDB();

var query =
    from q in rnQuery.AsCte("MyRowSet")
    where q.RowNum == 1
    select q;
```

I have simplified your OrderBy - CustomerID is not needed if you are making partition by this field.

Comment: `PartitioBy`? Would you like to buy an `n`?

Comment: But I faced "'RowNumber' is server-side method." Exception.

Comment: An exception was thrown while attempting to evaluate a LINQ query parameter expression. To show additional information call EnableSensitiveDataLogging() when overriding DbContext.OnConfiguring.

Comment: Probably you have to switch LIQN Translator  rnQuery = rnQuery.ToLinqToDB();

Comment: @Svyatoslav Danyliv - It just change my error to "Async operations for the LINQ provider 'LinqToDB.Linq.ExpressionQueryImpl`1' are not supported. You can implement a custom async adapter (DevExtreme.AspNet.Data.Async.IAsyncAdapter) and register it via 'DevExtreme.AspNet.Data.Async.CustomAsyncAdapters.RegisterAdapter'."

Comment: I don't think this should be a part of this extension. But I'll try to propose PR for DevExtreme.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/223280/discussion-between-sasan-k-and-svyatoslav-danyliv).