# translate row_number over partition to C# linq

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq

How to translate the following SQL query into C# Linq:

```
SELECT * FROM (
   SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY StuffConditionId, StuffId ORDER BY StuffDayOfYear) AS RowNumber
   FROM Stuff) rop
WHERE rop.RowNumber = 1;
```

Here is a partial dataset:

```
StuffId,StuffValue,StuffConditionId,StuffDayOfYear
2,9340,NULL,1
2,9340,NULL,2
2,9340,NULL,3
11,78,NULL,267
11,78,NULL,268
11,78,NULL,269
43,0,3,130
43,0,3,131
43,0,3,132
43,0,2,133
45,0,2,134
45,0,2,135
45,0,2,148
55,0,2,309
55,0,2,332
55,0,3,333
```

Answer Summary: The answer is to first build a in-memory list of stuffs, i.e. local list variable, then apply the LINQ query as shown in answer below.

Comment: Without additional extensions - no way. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64412492/implementation-of-partition-by-command-by-linq/64413634#64413634

Comment: use a GroupBy and then you can use the 2nd parameter on the Select which gives you an index. However a GroupBy, OrderBy and a First on each of the GroupBy's will also achieve this result. Give me some example data and associated SQL result for the above query and I'll craft the Linq query for you.

Comment: SvyatoslavDanyliv is right in a strict sense, but Carlo Bos noticed that the WHERE clause means OP is really just trying to grab the top item from each group. Depending on which version of which ORM you're using, that might be possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without some actual data I couldn't test this. But here's how this can be done, assuming `stuff` is your collection (aka table):

```
var firstInCollection = Stuff
    .OrderBy(x => x.StuffDayOfYear)
    .ToList() // Load in memory, then do groupby and select first due to EF Core
    .GroupBy(x => new { condition = x.StuffConditionId, stuff = x.StuffId })
    .Select(g => g.First());
```

Ok, I've tried this on a data table with a list of countries. Here are my results:

```
SELECT *
FROM (
   SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY SUBSTRING(CountryCode, 1, 1) ORDER BY CountryCode) AS RowNumber
   FROM Lookup.Country) rop
WHERE rop.RowNumber = 1;
```

and got the following results in SQL

[image]

Then I used the following Linq statement. This is using Linq2SQL in LinqPad connected to my Microsoft SQL Database:

```
Countries
    .OrderBy(c => c.CountryName)
    .GroupBy(c => c.CountryName[0])
    .Select(g => g.First())
```

And got the following result:

[image]

Which correlates with the SQL results.

Here's the example with your example data

```
void Main()
{
    var stuffs = new []
    {
        new Stuff { StuffId =  2, StuffValue = 9340, StuffConditionId = null, StuffDayOfYear = 1   },
        new Stuff { StuffId =  2, StuffValue = 9340, StuffConditionId = null, StuffDayOfYear = 2   },
        new Stuff { StuffId =  2, StuffValue = 9340, StuffConditionId = null, StuffDayOfYear = 3   },
        new Stuff { StuffId = 11, StuffValue =   78, StuffConditionId = null, StuffDayOfYear = 267 },
        new Stuff { StuffId = 11, StuffValue =   78, StuffConditionId = null, StuffDayOfYear = 268 },
        new Stuff { StuffId = 11, StuffValue =   78, StuffConditionId = null, StuffDayOfYear = 269 },
        new Stuff { StuffId = 43, StuffValue =    0, StuffConditionId =    3, StuffDayOfYear = 130 },
        new Stuff { StuffId = 43, StuffValue =    0, StuffConditionId =    3, StuffDayOfYear = 131 },
        new Stuff { StuffId = 43, StuffValue =    0, StuffConditionId =    3, StuffDayOfYear = 132 },
        new Stuff { StuffId = 43, StuffValue =    0, StuffConditionId =    2, StuffDayOfYear = 133 },
        new Stuff { StuffId = 45, StuffValue =    0, StuffConditionId =    2, StuffDayOfYear = 134 },
        new Stuff { StuffId = 45, StuffValue =    0, StuffConditionId =    2, StuffDayOfYear = 135 },
        new Stuff { StuffId = 45, StuffValue =    0, StuffConditionId =    2, StuffDayOfYear = 148 },
        new Stuff { StuffId = 55, StuffValue =    0, StuffConditionId =    2, StuffDayOfYear = 309 },
        new Stuff { StuffId = 55, StuffValue =    0, StuffConditionId =    2, StuffDayOfYear = 332 },
        new Stuff { StuffId = 55, StuffValue =    0, StuffConditionId =    3, StuffDayOfYear = 333 }
    };


    var firstInCollection = stuffs
        .OrderBy(x => x.StuffDayOfYear)
        .GroupBy(x => new { condition = x.StuffConditionId, stuff = x.StuffId })
        .Select(g => g.First())
        .Dump();
}

class Stuff
{
    public int StuffId { get; set; }
    public int StuffValue { get; set; }
    public int? StuffConditionId { get; set; }
    public int StuffDayOfYear { get; set; }
}
```

This results in the following:

[image]

Comment: I just tried on my data, it gets back an empty EntityQueryable<Stuff>, I think this works for one partition variable, if you try on more than one like in my case, it will have problem

Comment: I just realized that I needed to name the properties in the anonymous class (when there are more than 1 properties). This is working for me though. I've updated the answer above. This line: `.GroupBy(x => new { condition = x.StuffConditionId, stuff = x.StuffId })`

Comment: I recently learned that a `GroupBy().Select(g => g.First())` doesn't work in EF Core (in EF Core 2 it'll use in-memory evaluation, and in EF Core 3 it'll throw an exception). So be mindful of that if you're expecting to switch to .NET Core anytime soon.

Comment: I just tried the updated answer with named groupby variables, still the same, empty collection. @Stripling, I am using .net core 3.1 for this.

Comment: Sorry about it not being compatible with EF Core. I've tried the solution with your example data and it seems to return a result. I've updated my answer above.

Comment: Ok, I found that this works on locally in-memory list, doesn't work on dbcontext due to the 'Groupby client-side evaluation is not legal' exception. If I pull the records first, then apply this on that in-memory list, then it did go through without exception, but it gets back ALL records, instead of the first of each partition.

Comment: Please show what you are trying. I'm assuming you're doing a `.ToList() ` to load the data, then chain the above solution below the `.ToList()`?

Comment: Yes, I use the ToList to load the db table into a local variable (`var stuffs = _dbcontext.Stuff.ToList(); var filteredStuff = stuffs.OrderBy`... etc), then apply exactly the linq query as shown above

Comment: I would look at your data next. Maybe it's not what you expect, or not in the data-type you expect.

Comment: Ok, I made a typo on the second groupby variable, hence it is not working right, after correcting that typo, it is working correctly! Carlo, in the interest of others, please update your answer in that, you don't need to apply the .ToList after the OrderBy. But it IS necessary to use the .ToList to pull all DB records into a LOCAL list variable first, then the LINQ stuff would work. So, this might not be viable for a very large DBSet